# How can I allign my text correctly in Android studio?

Tags: android, weather

In my app I currently have two text views in an alert dialog to display the temperature and the weather description. The problem with this is that whenever the description changes, the alignment changes.

I tried having my layout as a relative layout and move around both of them with one depending on the other but this does not help me out. Any suggestions?

This is my current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/climaText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/climaText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening due to change in data size , when the data is increased it will wrap the data when you will use wrap_content . I suggest you can use a parent view and fix the height.here is the code, let me know if its working. thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250px">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/climaText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250px">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/climaText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```